# Could not calculate accuracy, sensitivity and specificity of segmented image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I could not able to calculate accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity of segmented image. I've segmented the image with my own algorithm and wanted to get the accuracy of the segmented image by comparing it with the ground truth image.

Whenever I try to execute this code, the output window freezes and only displays the output image. I want the value of accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity to be printed too.

Here in my code, the segmented image **erosion2** and ground truth image is **res**. Both the images are displaying but not showing accuracy when I do comparison.

```
`import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('dataset.tif')
cv.imshow('Input Image',img)

b,g,r= cv.split(img)
cv.imshow('Red Channel',r)
cv.imshow('Green Channel',g)
cv.imshow('Blue Channel',b)
img2= cv.bitwise_not(g)
cv.imshow('Processed Image',img2)

kernel3 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(13,13))

tophat = cv.morphologyEx(img2, cv.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel3)
cv.imshow('Top hat',tophat)

thres= 12
maxValue = 255
ret,thresh41 = cv.threshold(tophat,thres, maxValue,cv.THRESH_TOZERO)
th, dat = cv.threshold(tophat, thres, maxValue, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
cv.imshow('thresh',dat)
kernel1 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(2,2))
dilation = cv.dilate(dat,kernel1,iterations = 1)
erosion = cv.erode(dilation,kernel1,iterations = 1)
erosion1=cv.GaussianBlur(erosion,(5,5),0)
erosion1=cv.blur(erosion,(5,5),0)
x=cv.subtract(dilation,erosion1)
x = cv.medianBlur(x,5)
cv.imshow("op1",x)
b2=cv.add(erosion,x)
cv.imshow("fin",b2)
erosion2=cv.erode(b2,kernel1,iterations=1)
cv.imshow("result",erosion2)

res = cv.imread('manual1.tiff')
#cv.imshow('GroundTruth Image',img3)
res = cv.cvtColor(res, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(res.shape)
#def calC_accuracy(result, label):
tp = 0
fp = 0
tn = 0
fn = 0
i = 0
j = 0

print(np.unique(erosion2))
print(np.unique(res))
while i < erosion2.shape[0]:
    j = 0
while j < erosion2.shape[1]:
    if label[i,j] == 255:
        if erosion2[i,j] == res[i,j]:
            tp = tp + 1
else:
    fn = fn + 1

if erosion[i,j] == res[i,j]:
    tn = tn + 1
else:
    fp = fp + 1
j = j + 1
i = i + 1
print("TN =",tn,"FP =",fp)
print("FN =",fn,"TP =",tp)
print("Sensitivity = ",float(tp/(tp+fn+1)))
print("Specificity = ",float(tn/(tn+fp+1)))
print("Accuracy = ",float((tn+tp)/(fn+fp+1+tn+tp)))
#print("PPV = ",float(tp/(tp+fp+1)))
#return float(tp/(tp+fp+1))

#cv.imshow('result',erosion)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to cv.waitKey(0) or cv2.destroyAllWindows(), the program ends before it can show sensitivity and other values. You can use pdb module https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html to debug your python program so you can figure out where is the problem.